# JPA annotation for conditional update

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have two Entities

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "question", uniqueConstraints =
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "text"))
public class Question  implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String text;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "question", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, targetEntity = Answer.class)
    private Set<Answer> listAnswers = new HashSet<Answer>();
}


@Entity
public class Answer  implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String text;
    private Integer result = 0;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Question.class, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "question_id", nullable = false)
    private Question question;
}
```

When i try to merge() entity Question all data in Answer overwrite ("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" = "update"):

```
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(
            "some.package.settings", properties);
    assertTrue(emf.isOpen());
    EntityManager em  = emf.createEntityManager();

    em.getTransaction().begin();

    em.merge(question);

    if (em.getTransaction().isActive()) {
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }
    em.close();
    emf.close();
```

In entity Answer field result has values: 0, 1, 2. I need to prohibit the update record if the Answer.result > 0 .

There is such annotation or not? I saw @PreUpdate/@PostUpdate annotations. A can save data before update and restore if need, but may be exist another way?

Comment: when you set your answers try to do this `questions.getListAnswers().add(NEW_ITEM);`

Comment: I answered below with code

Answer (score 0):

My program parses same resource and generate list of questions with answers. I need to check question record with answers in DB. If question present i added only answers. If answer for question present too i need to update Answer.result field in value == 0.

```
public void testAnswersForQuestion() {

    Integer resultAnswer = question.getListAnswers().get(0).getResult();
    System.out.println("ans1 result: " + ans1.getResult());
    System.out.println("question answer result: " + resultAnswer);
    assertTrue(question.getListAnswers().size()>0);
    assertTrue(question.getListAnswers().size()==1);
    assertTrue(resultAnswer == 2);

    ans1.setResult(0);
    assertTrue(ans1.getResult()==0);

    System.out.println("----ADD ANSWER----");
    question.getListAnswersAsSet().add(ans1);
    assertTrue(question.getListAnswers().size()==1);
    resultAnswer = question.getListAnswers().get(0).getResult();
    assertTrue(resultAnswer == 0);

    System.out.println("----AFTER----");

    System.out.println("ans1 result: " + ans1.getResult());
    System.out.println("question answer result: " + resultAnswer);
}
```

All test passed. Output:

```
ans1 result: 2
question answer result: 2
----ADD ANSWER----
----AFTER----
ans1 result: 0
question answer result: 0
```

As you see field result was changed.  I need to prohibit the update record if the Answer.result > 0 .

Comment: `ans1` is not defined anywhere?

Comment: It defined in setUp() method.Answer a1 = new Answer("some answer", "right");
a1.setId(1L); 
q1.getListAnswersAsSet().add(a1);
this.ans1 = a1;

if ans1 create via constructor i receive two different objects and listAnswers.size() ==2.

Comment: I think for speed to take this check out of JPA. It will probably be simply. Apparently the annotation I need is missing